# cannot open database, on code execution - shows exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, database-connection, connection-string

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cannot open database
>   "aspnet-mywebsite-20150813211505" requested by the login. The login
>   failed.

Trying to connect on local .mdf database in visual studio 2013 - web forms. 
Created database and c# code for connecting to database. Error shows when i try to execute :

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-mywebsite-20150813211505;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Users;");
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    con.Close();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-mywebsite-20150813211505.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
```

If this does't work, try to connect to this database using the "Add New Data Source" wizzard and copy the connection string from the auto generated connection string located in the app.config.